# checkbox - checked will change textbox value

Tags: jquery

what i want is that changing textbox value with checkbox. when checkbox is checked, textbox must be '2020-01-01'

I did this

```
$('#checkPub').click(function() {
   $("#demo1").val('2020-01-01');
});
```

It gives only me the checkbox as output why? It does not change the textbox value

Comment: Can you add your HTML code please?

Comment: Are you binding the event handler when `#checkPub` exists? There is not enough information to help you... please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: can you show the html as well.

Comment: check this fiddle. it is working as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/rutwik/f2wTU/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#checkPub').click(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) 
  $("#demo1").val('2020-01-01');
  else
  $("#demo1").val('');
});
```

Comment: Eventually yes (apart from syntax errors), but if even the OP's simple version does not work, this won't either. And code without any  explanation is hardly helpful.